# Not Able to access expansion file content

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I am using this code, but I am not able to access the expansion file content, i want to show gif image from expansion file, how can i do?

String packageName = getPackageName();
                    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

```
                File expPath = new File(root.toString() + "/Android/obb/" + packageName);

                try {
                    if (expPath.exists()) {
                        String strMainPath = expPath
                                + File.separator
                                + "main."
                                + getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                                getPackageName(), 0).versionCode + "."
                                + packageName + ".obb";

                        File f = new File(strMainPath);

                        if (f.exists()) {
                            Log.e("Path ", "=====>Exists");
                        } else {
                            Log.e("Path ", "=====> Not Exists");
                        }


                        ZipResourceFile zip = new ZipResourceFile(strMainPath);
                        InputStream iStream = zip.getInputStream("stage1_popup.gif");

                        BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        option.inPurgeable = true;

                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream, null, option);
                        Glide.with(SampleDownloaderActivity.this).load(bitmap).into(image);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
```

http://prntscr.com/kp25qz

Answer (score 0):

The Play APK expansions files library is completely open source, and you can see [the sourcecode for ZipResourceFile here](https://github.com/google/play-apk-expansion/blob/master/zip_file/src/com/google/android/vending/expansion/zipfile/ZipResourceFile.java#L242).

It looks like stage1_popup.gif is not in your obb file. To investigate it, why not use [adb pull](http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-pull) to get the file off your device and see what it actually contains. Or download the source code and attach to your IDE so you can step into the getInputStream() call and see where it is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28096056/4825703), `ZipResourceFile` isn't able to deal with too much little files and neither is `ZipFile`. So try to divide your files in more directories.

Also, it's quite possible that there isn't any file with the name, `stage1_popup.gif`.

Alternatively, you can get all Entries via `zipResourceFile.getAllEntries()` and findout if the file exists.